# How does IOMMU and/or Linux kernel handle DMA that span a page boundary?

Tags: kernel, driver, dma-attack

I am looking into how DMA works at the device driver and kernel level in the Linux kernel.
I observed that access control to DMA buffers from IO devices is performed by the IOMMU and IOMMU driver in the kernel.

I will provide an example to explain my question:

Let's say there is an NVMe storage device connected to the system with an IOMMU.
Consider the scenario where the device is reading a 4KB page from memory using DMA.
The device driver will map the memory that the device needs to read through the IOMMU and IO page tables.
Now, the storage device has read access to the 4KB buffer, let's say this buffer starts from the physical address 0x4fece000 and ends at 0x4fecf000.

Note: Assume IOMMU is enabled and the device can only see the IO virtual addresses belonging to the above physical addresses.

My questions:

1. Who decides the maximum transfer size (or payload size) the device can read in a single read DMA access?
2. Let's say the device can read 32 Bytes in a single read, can the device start a read operation from the address 0x4fecefff (address of the last byte of the mapped memory) and read physical addresses that are not mapped to the device?
3. If not, how does the IOMMU control the access in this scenario? Does it divide the DMA read into two reads and perform translation separately?

I really appreciate any help in understanding how IOMMU handles this scenario.